# Permalink button on bottom of Questions page appears to be broken

Tags: discussion, bug, broken-link, permalink

I saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261591/purpose-of-permalink-in-new-navigation) question after fooling around with the [permalink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) link on the bottom of the questions page to see what it was doing.

According to that post it looks like the permalink should change the URL in my browser, but it appears to do nothing. The URL stays the same. Nothing gets copied to my clipboard either which would be way more handy than having to notice the URL change in the browser, but would still not be immediately apparent. If it had similar functionality to the "share" button on the bottom of posts that would be nice. Or just not even have the permalink there if it has no functionality on the default tabs.

**Edit:** A permalink is a link that you should click and it should give you a URL that allows you to return to that exact same result set or page anytime in the future. It should be content based. If the argument is that the permalink on the questions page is doing exactly what it should because it reloads the page, then by that theory ***every*** URL is a permalink. There has to be distinction between the two. Now aside from all of the semantics here, there is clearly about half the people who have voted on this question who agree it's broken or should be renamed, and the other half seem to think it's not a bug at all and that's how a permalink works. With all of that aside - it to me that regardless if that is exactly how it is supposed to work, it seems a little bit off. I'm proposing to update the naming to just say "Refresh the page" or something that is obvious on what it does.

Is this broken or am I just missing something obvious here?

When clicked, it just reloads this URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Here is a screenshot of the specific spot I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: The permanent link is the same as the question url. The question id never changes, only the slug at the end, which is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about the Permalink on the "Questions" tab lower right corner. I would take a screenshot but I'm on my phone now.

Comment: The permalink on the questions tab links to the questions tab, which is the same URL as is already in the address bar. If you make a new tab (on the new nav), or go to a tag feed (on the old nav system) it will again be the same URL that is in the address bar. The permanent link is the same as the URL of the current page.

Comment: @TinyGiant Sorry - I'm a bit confused if you're just agreeing with me or if you're explaining how it is working... it sounds like you're agreeing?

Comment: No I'm explaining how it works, that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: What do you _expect_ the permalink of the Questions page to link to?

Comment: @CodeCaster Why even have it then?

Comment: The link itself says it's for sharing. Note that the permalink works for any tab on the new nav so you can create a filtered list and share that with others.

Comment: @BSMP so perhaps the correct functionality would be to hide it on the default tabs and then show it on custom tabs?

Comment: Well, it's not really hurting anything by being on the default tabs. It probably helps people navigating by keyboard get back to the top of the page as well.

Comment: @BSMP It lead me to confusion

Comment: I'd say it's a design flaw...

Comment: @cybermonkey I'd have to agree, yet there are others who are downvoting - I wish they would chime in more.

Comment: Your expectation of what a permalink should be is faulty, you're looking for an archiving service.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Consider this scenario - I have a customised home page (because I have my own tags highlighted and ignored). Because of this, SO changes the list of questions that it shows me. If I hover over permalink, the tooltip says "a link to this question list suitable for sharing". If I send that link to someone else, they'll see a list of questions but it will be an entirely different list of questions. It's not a link to _this_ question list, it's a link to _the_ question list. If my expectation is wrong, it's been set wrong by the site itself

Answer (score 1):

The question list uses some kind of AJAX to fetch pages beyond the first. Clicking the page number <kbd>5</kbd> makes the browser load `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes?page=5&pagesize=15&layout=compact` and update the current page with the received data.

Because the site doesn't rewrite the browser history, the URL that the browser shows you stays the same, while the content refreshes as you navigate through the pages.

The permalink enables you to link to a specific page. The link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes?page=5` for example, loads the full page and *then* rewrite the history to make it look like you're on `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes`.

It's not that I see the use for linking to a specific page, as pages change over time, but it's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: So if I click on the permalink button, what exactly happens other than bringing me to the top of the page if you're on http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions and click the permalink on that page?

Comment: A permalink is not for clicking, it's for sharing or bookmarking. If you do click it, nothing unexpected happens: the browser will re-load the current page.

Comment: Shouldn't it just say "refresh page" or something then? If you go to an actual question (just like this one) and click on "share" then that has a permalink in it where you can send the link to someone else. The permalink should really be renamed if it has no usage other than reloading the page, unless I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: (from that same Wikipedia page) "A permalink is a URL that points to a *specific* web page". The permalink on http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions does not point to a specific web page, it points to a dynamic page. If I refresh the page, then the content changes. It should redirect you to a permanent link to the specific set of questions on that page like this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314986/4826740. Though I don't even see a real need to have a permalink on the questions tab, and perhaps it could just be changed to say "Back to top", or "Refresh page" or something.

Comment: That's alright, but none of that is in your question. Your question is talking about bugs, non-changing URLs and refreshing pages, while none of that is relevant because the URL does exactly what it should do. I too question the usability of a permalink to the Questions page, but it is not "broken".

Comment: It works exactly as it should if you know how per makings are supposed to work. @maxshuty

Comment: It is supposed to reload the page and that's it @TinyGiant? Permalinks are supposed to give you a URL to a page that is a permanent link to that page so if I send you a permalink to this answer, next year if you click that link it still leads you right to this answer. The permalink on the questions tab does nothing like that.

Comment: @maxshuty as I [said two weeks ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314571/permalink-button-on-bottom-of-questions-page-appears-to-be-broken/314986?noredirect=1#comment296240_314986), try to write a proper bug report. Nothing which you claim in comments is in your question. If you expect a permalink on a Questions page to link to that view of those exact questions at any later moment in time, then please say so.

Comment: @maxshuty it is supposed to link to the current page. There is no possible way to link to the questions page as you saw it forever, because answers get deleted, titles get changed, and other such variables, so it provides with a url to the page you are currently on. It provides you with a url to the current page, not a url to view the exact content you are currently viewing. If you want a link to the current page, use the permalink. If you want a link to the exact content you're viewing, use an archiving service like [the wayback machine](http://archive.org/web/)

Comment: @TinyGiant Why have it say permalink then? It should just say refresh page? That is sort of my whole argument here - the permalink is not doing what a permalink should. I know you argue that it is doing what it should, but by definition (from Wikipedia) "a permalink remains unchanged indefinitely". This page changes. It is not a permalink - it is a page refresh. Either they should make it say something else, or they should make it return the same result set (which seems pointless for that page, but it would be the proper use of a permalink). CodeCaster - I edited the question for you.

Comment: @maxshuty it is doing exactly what it should, your expectation is faulty, you're looking for an archiving service.

Comment: @TinyGiant By your definition, every single URL on the internet is a permalink, right? If the permalink is not content based and just a URL to a page, then every URL could just as easily be called a permalink.

Comment: Not necessarily, if the location is altered through Ajax without changing the rules in the address bar, you will want a link to the current location. You're getting a link to the location, not necessarily the exact content. @maxshuty

Comment: @maxshuty "Permalinks are supposed to give you a URL to a page that is a permanent link to that page so if I send you a permalink to this answer, next year if you click that link it still leads you right to this answer." If an answer is deleted, the link will take you to the question page but you won't see the answer (unless you're a 10k'er and can see deleted posts). If a question is deleted, the link will give you a 404 (again, unless you're a 10k'er). If a post is edited, the link will take you to the current version, not the version when you copied the link.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot So again, if it's not that then we probably shouldn't call it a permalink, right? Because by that standard every single link on any page is a permalink (with the exception of the the scenario TinyGiant mentioned)